# Why not all cipher suites are enabled by default in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

What is the disadvantage of:

```
sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites( sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites() );
```

Why is this not the default setting? Are there some security risk with some of it?

Comment: SSL v2 might be supported but you should never use it under any circumstances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all cipher suites are equal. The list of supported cipher suites can include NULL ciphersuites (no encryption or no authentication or both) or other weak cipher suites and you probably don't want this to be enabled?